# Background color using rgb on android (XML preferred)?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, colors

It's silly, but how to put a background rgb on android?

I'm trying to put a background of RGB color, but I can not find how to do.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background= ?
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

I've done it this way, but does not work

```
Color.rgb(200,0,0)
```

Comment: use **#ff0000** to get Red color

Comment: The problem is that I need to do it in RGB format @NabinKhadka

Comment: why you need to do in RGB any strong reason? @Carlos Uriel Santiago

Comment: school work :( @Kinjal

Comment: man you can not use RGB color in xml (layout) you have to do by programmatically like `anyView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(200, 00, 00));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set RGB color with hex code in Android, like Hex Code #RRGGBB

Here are some sample colors:

```
Color   Hex RGB  Decimal Code
White   #FFFFFF (255,255,255)
Red     #FF0000 (255,0,0)
Lime    #00FF00 (0,255,0)
Blue    #0000FF (0,0,255)
```

For example you want to set color blue in your View background

```
android:background= "#0000FF"
```

It is always better to define your **color** in `Color res` folder.

Answer (score 3):

**Not sure** if you can use RGB values from XML. But I am pretty sure you can do this from Java. Create an instance of your component and use method `setBackgroundColor()`. Use as following:

```
yourComponent.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(200, 00, 00));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
View.setBackgroundColor(rgb(255,0,0))
```

You may get an error Import the

```
import android.graphics.Color.rgb
```